# How does this C# code get done in functional languages (F#? Haskel?)

Tags: c#, functional-programming, c#-to-f#

How could I write this C# code in F# or Haskel, or a similar functional language?

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"\\ad1\\Users\aanodide\Desktop\APIUserGuide.txt");

// XSDs are lines 375-471
var slice = lines.Skip(374).Take(471-375+1);

var kvp = new List<KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>>(); 
slice.Aggregate(kvp, (seed, line) => 
{
    if(line.StartsWith("https"))
        kvp.Last().Value.Add(line);
    else
        kvp.Add(
            new KeyValuePair<string,List<string>>(
                line, new List<string>()
            )
        );
    }
    return kvp;
});
```

Comment: Actually that's really functional-like... no (visible) loops, just functions...

Comment: The MSDN docs have information on [how to program in F#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233154.aspx)...

Comment: @digEmAll: It's mutating objects though. (`.Add()`)

Comment: @recursive: yeah, that's true

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, if I read your code correctly, your input looks something like this:

```
[...]
Foo
https://example1.com
https://example2.com
Bar
https://example3.com
Baz
Xyzzy
https://example4.com
[...]
```

From this, you want the headers grouped with the URLs below them. Here's a Haskell program that does this:

```hs
import Data.List (isPrefixOf)

groupUrls :: [String] -> [(String, [String])]
groupUrls [] = []
groupUrls (header:others) = (header, urls) : groupUrls remaining
  where (urls, remaining) = span (isPrefixOf "https") others

main = do
    input <- readFile "\\\\ad1\\\\Users\\aanodide\\Desktop\\APIUserGuide.txt"
    let slice = take (471 - 375 + 1) $ drop 374 $ lines input
    let kvp = groupUrls slice
    print kvp
```

Output:

```hs
[("Foo",["https://example1.com","https://example2.com"]),("Bar", ["https://example3.com"]),("Baz",[]),("Xyzzy",["https://example4.com"])]
```

The key function of interest here is [`span`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.1/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html#v:span), which is used here to take the consecutive lines starting with `"https"` and return them together with the remaining lines, which are then dealt with recursively.